# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AdminTemplate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, http-status-code-404, servlet-mapping

for the first this error seems really silly and easy to fix but the problem is everything seems oke and i have no idea what cause it.I tried to configure this web project with java configuration and also xml and i get the same 404 error code.

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AdminTemplate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'

If anyone can help me here i would really appreciate it.
Here is my code:

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.admin.controller" />


<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

a simple controller

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage() {

    return "index";

      }
  }
```

and a simple jsp which is not important.

My project structure is like this:

[image]

But ofcourse if i set in the web.xml

`<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>`

and move the index.jsp file from jsp folder to webapps it works.
Anyone has an idea what can cause this?Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I tested other project which worked in the past and now i get the same 404 error.

Comment: which url you using?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/AdminTemplate// (with one slash after aplication name)

Comment: try localhost:8080/springapp/AdminTemplate

Comment: Its the same.The problem is not with the link or the config in my opinion i think it should be a tomcat error or something else....because i have other projects which worked in the past but now i get the same 404 error

Comment: Did you see the controller starting when spring star, you need to see something like url:/AdminTemplate in the logs, if not Controller annotation is not recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem temporarily buy changing the whole XML configuration to Java based configuration, after that i become 100% sure the problem is not with the code.I leave a link here for the other problem maybe someone will face the same.

[Tomcat error? Or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654347/eclipsetomcat-or-something-else)

Answer (score 0):

404 error occurs due to client side resource problem and spell mistake also it should not be `index.htm` it should be `index.jsp` & if u Want to use `index.jsp` inside views folder use full path like shown below :-

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: That dosen't matter that i have index.htm in the web.xml since i don't want to access it from there.With that works as i mentioned ebove.

Comment: add the full path `/WEB-INF/views/index.hbm` or jsp or html it will short out the problem and in ur project hierarchy its was jsp thats y i was telling abt jsp

Comment: That has nothing to do with this...you can get rid of that part completely, and if you add the full path like you said still wont work.
What are you trying to explain is to access the jsp but,how you said you don't even need the controller.Just move the index.jsp to webapp folder and its done.This won't solve my problem.