# Tomcat error? Or something else?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ide

My problem is that sometimes when i'm working in Eclipse IDE (using Tomcat 8),something goes wrong.It gives me a HTTP 404 error code, which seems obvious for the first look, but the problem is not with the configuration or anything like that,because this happens even with working projects.The only difference i see is that the tomcat is starting faster when i run the project(then i know i will get a 404 error),even if that worked before.Or its loading faster as i mentioned but when i change something its not "loading" that.But here comes the interesting thing,if i make changes in the design which worked already, the changes appears after a refresh/restart.But for example if i delete or change a controller that keeps working or not(depends how was before)One more interesting thing.When i get 404 error and i see its loading faster, and i try to start the server again without stop it,its not asking me if i want to restart it...just brings up the index page.So sometimes its not working the project at all....(404 error)...and sometimes just not "updadeting" it.When this happens i try to clean tomcat/web directory, clean the project, restart the tomcat several times or just restart Eclipse.But even all this sometimes has no effect,and i loose a lot of time with it...
Anyone faced something similar before?And have a solution for this? Or an idea what causing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to edit your question, start with proper punctuation and capitalization. Adding an indignant message about downvoting does nothing to make your question more understandable.

Comment: i dont need to show code because the problem is not with that....i mentioned it above.....

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, It's hard to determine your issue, but as deep I recognized you must some bits slipped in Tomcat Server Configuration in Eclipse Server.

[Install and Configure Apache Tomcat Web Server in Eclipse IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLgquZ2FiuQ)

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your code so that we can see what is the problem here.
Anyway try reinstalling Tomcat and follow the configuration steps. The error [ERROR 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) usually caused when the server could not reach what you requested. In your case the Tomcat is not starting. Reinstall and reconfigure it again.

Comment: I reinstalled many time reconfigured it but the same happens some time...anyway i migrated to STS and there everything works fine.